# Merge two queries without duplicating rows in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to merge two queries using one column (which contains duplicate values, although the exact same amount of duplicates for the same values in both queries) as key; but whenever I expand the merged table, all rows get twice the duplicates.

I am not an expert in Power Query and I've tried several things, including different tipes of join (left, full, right, etc.) and the result is always the same.

The setup is like this:

Query Table 1:

```
|   Name  |Extension|Folder Path  |Product Name|Destination Path|
|File1.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductA  |  c:/otherpath/ |
|File2.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductA  |  c:/otherpath/ |
|File4.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductB  |  c:/otherpath/ |
|File3.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductC  |  c:/otherpath/ |
|File8.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductC  |  c:/otherpath/ |
|File9.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductC  |  c:/otherpath/ |
```

Query Table 2:

```
|productid|productSKU|Product Name|                    ImageIDs                  |
|   0001  | sku0001  |  ProductA  |          productA-1.jpg, productA-2.jpg      |
|   0002  | sku0002  |  ProductB  |                  productB-1.jpg              |
|   0003  | sku0003  |  ProductC  |productC-1.jpg, productc-2.jpg, productc-3.jpg|
```

Desired output (I'm building a dynamic renaming function, to rename all files with the names of ImageIDs:

```
|   Name  |Extension|Folder Path  |Product Name|Destination Path|    ImageID    |
|File1.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductA  |  c:/otherpath/ | productA-1.jpg|
|File2.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductA  |  c:/otherpath/ | productA-2.jpg|
|File4.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductB  |  c:/otherpath/ | productB-1.jpg|
|File3.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductC  |  c:/otherpath/ | productC-1.jpg|
|File8.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductC  |  c:/otherpath/ | productC-2.jpg|
|File9.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductC  |  c:/otherpath/ | productC-3.jpg|
```

What I've tried unsucsessfully in short is:

- Split the ImageIDs column into rows on Query 2 -> Then Merge Queries using *Product Name* as Key -> Expand the ImageIDs column in the merged query.
- Create a third query with unique *Product Name* values -> Merge the other two queries to the newly created -> Expand the desired columns as needed.
- Merge the two queries first using *Product Name* as key -> Then expand the ImageIDs column in the merged query -> Split the ImageIDs column into rows.
- Group the table in Query 1 by *Product Name* -> Merge the two queries using *Product Name* as key (which now has only unique values on each query) -> expand the name table in the merged query.

I'm guessing I should use some kind of index column that counts the duplication of values in *Product Name* but I don't really know that, nor I understand why is it not working, but any of the options above output something like this:

```
|   Name  |Extension|Folder Path  |Product Name|Destination Path|    ImageID    |
|File1.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductA  |  c:/otherpath/ | productA-1.jpg|
|File1.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductA  |  c:/otherpath/ | productA-2.jpg|
|File2.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductA  |  c:/otherpath/ | productA-1.jpg|
|File2.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductA  |  c:/otherpath/ | productA-2.jpg|
|File4.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductB  |  c:/otherpath/ | productB-1.jpg|
|File3.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductC  |  c:/otherpath/ | productC-1.jpg|
|File3.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductC  |  c:/otherpath/ | productC-2.jpg|
|File3.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductC  |  c:/otherpath/ | productC-3.jpg|
|File8.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductC  |  c:/otherpath/ | productC-1.jpg|
|File8.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductC  |  c:/otherpath/ | productC-2.jpg|
|File8.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductC  |  c:/otherpath/ | productC-3.jpg|
|File9.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductC  |  c:/otherpath/ | productC-1.jpg|
|File9.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductC  |  c:/otherpath/ | productC-2.jpg|
|File9.jpg|   .jpg  |c:/someroute/|  ProductC  |  c:/otherpath/ | productC-3.jpg|
```

As I mentioned above, I'm trying to create a renaming function, so files with random names, get the name of the product they are representing.

Comment: Does it matter which of `File1.jpg` or `File2.jpg` is in the same row as `productA-1.jpg`?

Comment: Hi @Alexis No it doesn't matter.

It would be interesting to know if it did, but for this exercise it doesnt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index columns should sort this out assuming `Table 2` has the same number of rows as `Table 1` after splitting `ImageIDs` to new rows.

1. Expand `Table 2` to new rows.
2. Sort the expanded `Table 2` by `Product Name` and `ImageId`.
3. Add an index column to `Table 2`.
4. Sort `Table 1` by `Product Name` and `Name`.
5. Add an index column to `Table 1`.
6. Merge `Table 2` onto `Table 1` using the index columns to match on.
7. Expand the `ImageId` column from `Table 2`.

Comment: Thanks @Alexis it did the trick, I was suspecting index columns but didn't new a regular index column would sort it out, I thought it was required to count and number each duplicate; now I assume that would be required in case the number of rows is not the same.

Comment: Yeah, it would be more painful with different table sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Try uncheck FuzzyNestedJoin when merge.
I just solved the same issue with this method.
The cause might be that a similar kay column value was matched and returned.